# Application of Chow theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In peters Book "AN INTRODUCTION TO COMPLEX ALGEBRAIC GEOMETRY" I find this exercice : Prove that holomorphic maps between projective manifolds are morphisms.

I think it is just an application of Chow theorem. My idea is to take the graph of the holomorphic map $f : V \to W$ which is a complex submanifold of $\mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^m$. By using the Segre emmbeding $\phi$ it is a submanifold of $\mathbb{P}^{nm+m+n}$ then it is an algebrais projective set by Chow theorem. i.e, $\Gamma_f = V(F_1\circ\phi, ..., F_m \circ \phi)$ withs $F_i$ is polynomial in $nm+n+m$ variables. I don't know how to process now to conclude that $f$ is locally given by polynomials.